# Jave Segmentation fault on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, linux, segmentation-fault, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run Java in Raspberry Pi - Rasbian.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME =    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/
echo $PATH =      /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/grails/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/bin/

which java   =    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre/bin/java


pi@raspberrypi ~ $ java
```

**Segmentation fault**

I have spent a day on this and am lost, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe that variant of Java wasn't compiled to work on ARM?

Comment: Hi, you have to go with Java SE embedded setup for Raspberry bi to run java check this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html

Comment: that was it, thanks.  Java SE did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java SE with Hard FLoating Point did the trick for those looking.